# Has the Thomas Wayne Batman ever Appeared Outside the Flashpoint storyline?

Tags: dc, batman, flashpoint

One of the main things that was changed during the events of the DC storyline Flashpoint was Thomas Wayne becoming Batman after the deaths of Martha & Bruce. This Batman was much darker and I was wondering if it ever made any other appearances (note: I am excluding the animated film Justice League: The Flashpoint Paradox, as it is basically the same storyline).

Comment: I disagree with this being a duplicate. I think that what he's asking about is if that particular Batman has been referred to since the Flashpoint series ended, not whether there have been other Batmans who were Thomas Wayne.

Answer (score 3):

The DC Wikia has a list of the [Flashpoint Batman's appearances](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Thomas_Wayne_(Flashpoint_Timeline)/Appearances), which includes the following comics that at least do not have Flashpoint in their name although I'm not familiar enough with them to tell of they just omitted said name:

- [Justice League Volume 2-40](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Justice_League_Vol_2_40)
- [Convergence: Superman Again Volume 1-2](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Convergence:_Superman_Vol_1_2)
- [Convergence: Superman Again Volume 1-1](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Convergence:_Superman_Vol_1_1)
- [Booster Gold Volume 2-45](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Booster_Gold_Vol_2_45)

Comment: Plus "The Button", and lots of chapters in the Rebirth run, notably "City of Bane".